# How to get the values true or false depending on a list of checkbox checked or not in Grails

Tags: grails, parameters, checkboxlist

I have check boxes in a list

**HTML Code**

```
<g:checkBox id="isBookable_${index}" class=" isBookable" style = "width :auto" name='isBookable' value='${careProviderScheduleExceptionInstance?.isBookable}'  />
```

**Problem**

When I get the list of this checkbox i.e isBookable in params, the values for only the checkboxes that are checked comes in the list and the value comes as on and not true.
I want the values should come as true or false based on if the checkbox is checked or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Grails `g:checkbox` does some shenanigans for the binding magic to work correctly when you do something like:

```
def schedule = new Schedule(params)
```

So that `schedule.bookable` would get populated correctly.  I've never been a big fan of how it works but it is what it is and at the end of the day, it does work for typical use cases.

You have to remember that per the HTML spec, you're not going to get unchecked checkboxes passed in on a form submit.  So looking for false is a moot point.  What you would have to do is take the ones that do get checked (and submitted) and compare that against a list of possible bookable 'schedules'.

A work around would be to use Javascript to submit your form and pass in all the checkbox's with whatever value you want mapped to the correct instance.